# Magento Varnish cache: How to find route name of module to exclude from cache?

Tags: magento-1.7, varnish

Magento Varnish cache: How to find route name of module to exclude from cache?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

You can get route of frontend pages modules name by using above line of code in to your any template file. e.g footer.phtml

You can use `print_r` with above line of code.